# Missing Right Parenthesis - Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am writing this query to create a table in Oracle DB, but I get the error `ORA-00907 Missing Right Parenthesis`. 
Please, help.

```
 create table stagingFeed 
(
  eff_date nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
  subj_id nvarchar(100),
  name_1 nvarchar(100),
  code nvarchar(100),
  rt nvarchar(100)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no data type `NVARCHAR` in Oracle. You should use either `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR2`. The latter is generally preferred:

```
create table stagingFeed 
(
  eff_date nvarchar2(100) NOT NULL,
  subj_id nvarchar2(100),
  name_1 nvarchar2(100),
  code nvarchar2(100),
  rt nvarchar2(100)
);
```